# How do I alert admin users when their account has timed out

Tags: javascript, php, session, alert, logout

The website I program for is a high school newspaper. Lately, the admin page has been having a trending issue. When by the time users have created an article, they have been logged out due to a set time limit. I want to program in an alert to tell users they have been logged out so that they can copy their article and paste it back in place. This is our timeout code:

```
    // Kill Session if session end exists.
    if ($_GET['endsession']) {
        unset($_SESSION['name']);
        unset($_SESSION['access']);
        unset($_COOKIE['username']);
        setcookie("username","",time() - 3600);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/admin.php");
    }
```

I have tried placing a javascript alert under the [ session_destroy(); ] and above the [ setcookie("username","",time() - 3600); ], but that resulted in  nothing happening. I also tried placing it above the [ session_destroy(); ], but that made the page not even time anyone out.

How do I get a simple Javascript alert to run when the function [ session_destroy(); ] runs?

Comment: putting a js alert under session_destroy would be pointless. if it's before the header call, it'll kill the header. if it's after, it'll likely never get displayed because the browser will be loading the next page anyways.

Comment: Would it be an option to keep the session alive while browser window is open? I think it's better to prevent the timeout of the session while someone works on an article  instead of telling the user that his work is _lost_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you check - before unsetting the session - if there are, let's say, five minutes left?

```
if($_GET['endsession'] < time() + 5*60) {
    //alert the user
}

if($_GET['endsession']) {
    //your code to unset the session
}
```

Assuming `$_GET['endsession']` contains a timestamp. If this is not the case you may as well transform it or whatsoever, but I think the general idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your body tag:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(function() {window.alert('You have been logged out');},600000);">
```

This will put an alert in the browser at 10 minutes (600 seconds / 600,000ms) saying "You have been logged out".

You can also do it in the body for the same effect:

```
<script>window.setTimeout(function() {window.alert('You have been logged out');},600000);</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: This didnt work. Its a php file and changing it to html messed with the main login function. Also, if that method did work, that would time the user since they reached the page, not since they logged in. Also, I did try to add this within the php file, but that did not work.

Comment: Yes, you have to add the code to the HTML part of a page (add to your body tag, just add "onload=..." to the existing tag, or the second script anywhere on the page). Logins are usually timed from last activity (10 minutes from last page request), not from the time they logged in. You may want to double-check that, since it's really uncommon to have that kind of a timeout.

Comment: PHP code must go between `<?php` and `?>` tags. HTML can go anywhere on most pages (but only one `<body>` tag is allowed). Javascript between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags executes immediately, so putting the second script in my answer anywhere between the body tags will create a timeout alert.