# PHP session timeout with or without activity

Tags: php

I'm trying to set php session to expire with our without browser activity.
I have tried to read forums, here on stackoverflow and can't.
The session still active if we have browser activity.

Comment: You essentially need a cron job or scheduled task to accomplish this. You can also do something with javascript `setTimeout()` to send an AJAX request to kill the session.

Comment: Are you looking to boot the user even if they are actively using the web page?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to handle that manually. Something roughly along these lines:

```
if(!$_SESSION['started']) {
    // This is a new session, let's keep track of when it was started
    $_SESSION['started'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['started'] > $maxlifetime) {
   // We've hit our max lifetime, session should be destroyed
   session_destroy();
}
```

Note that the user won't realize their session has expired until the next pageload. If you want them to be notified immediately (or close to it) even if they are just sitting on a page, then you'll need to employ some sort of ajax poll to check the session.

Comment: I think this is what @Frank wants. If he wants a user notice, use the first comment or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104231/how-do-i-alert-admin-users-when-their-account-has-timed-out/20104339#20104339)

Comment: @Frank Did this help with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could expire inactive sessions with a cron job, or try something like this:
 1. Store a timestamp in a session variable.
 2. Check/Update the variable on page load.
 3. If the timestamp is too old, force a logout event from your
    site/app.